# trouble parsing json in powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I have the below JSON which is just a bit of the file but illustrates it.

I am not that experienced with JSON and I have tried a lot of the examples that I could find but they only seem to show JSON that is just key/value pairs. I've seen a few to target arrays but I cant translate them to my particular JSON

for example I'm trying to get that the 'SavedPlayerDataVersion' is equal to 8 into a variable and I've put it into an object but I cant figure out how to target that particular item within the array and object

could anyone point me in the right direction please?

Thank you

```
{
    "profileVersion": 1,
    "profile": {
        "id": 0,
        "class": "PrimalPlayerDataBP_C",
        "names": ["PrimalPlayerDataBP_C_29", "ArkGameMode", "PersistentLevel", "Aberration_P", "/Game/Maps/Aberration/Aberration_P"],
        "properties": [{
            "name": "SavedPlayerDataVersion",
            "type": "IntProperty",
            "value": 8
        }, {
            "name": "HexagonCount",
            "type": "IntProperty",
            "value": 106860
        }, {
            "name": "MyPersistentBuffDatas",
            "type": "ArrayProperty",
            "arrayType": "ObjectProperty",
            "value": [1, 2, 3, 4]
        }],
        "extra": null
    }
}
```

```
            "type": "IntProperty",
            "value": 8
        }, {
            "name": "HexagonCount",
            "type": "IntProperty",
            "value": 6800
        }, {
            "name": "NumChibiLevelUpsData",
            "type": "IntProperty",
            "value": 2
        }, {
            "name": "MyData",
            "type": "StructProperty",
            "structType": "PrimalPlayerDataStruct",
            "value": [{
                "name": "PlayerDataID",
                "type": "UInt64Property",
                "value": 656195017
            }, {
                "name": "UniqueID",
                "type": "StructProperty",
                "structType": "UniqueNetIdRepl",
                "value": {
                    "unk": 8,
                    "netId": "76561198046328344"
                }
            }
```

I have edited the question after the original answers as I realised that what I also needed to access was a 'level' deeper. so it would be getting at "PlayerDataID"

I tried `$value = ($jsonobj.profile.properties.mydata | Where-Object { $_.name -eq "PlayerDataID" }).value`  but that isnt getting it for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON is exactly key-value pairs, so handling it like an object in PowerShell is the way to go. Start with `ConvertFrom-Json` and put the result in a variable, let's say *$myJson*.

`$myJson.profile.class` would net you *PrimalPlayerDataBP_C*. That's how you access nested properties. As for the arrays, you can iterate through them with `foreach`, get specific values with `where` or `select`, depends on what you need actually.

```
# This one returns the version number
$version = ($myJson.profile.properties | Where {$_.name -eq "SavedPlayerDataVersion"}).value

# This one checks whether version is 8
$isVersion8 = $NULL -ne `
($myJson.profile.properties | Where {$_.name -eq "SavedPlayerDataVersion" -and $_.value -eq 8})
```

**Be careful** when accessing array items using their index, as you never can be sure that the item with a specific index is the one you're looking for.

As I'm writing this answer, @Theo beat me to it, so kudos to him for the one-liner.

**EDIT:**
Including a step-by-step example for clarity's sake. You can do the same with fewer lines.

```
# Get an array of properties
$properties = $myJson.profile.properties

# Select the property with the required name from the array
$myData = $properties | Where {$_.name -eq "MyData"}

# MyData is multivalued, so need to use 'Where' again
$playerDataId = $myData.value | Where {$_.name -eq "PlayerDataID"}

# Value you are looking for
$playerDataId.value
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer, I've editted my original question as I realised that also needed to extract "PlayerDataID" from an array within the "mydata" key. so would I just used that to get the whole data of the keep and then to loop through it to get what I want

Comment: I've added a more detailed example to show how to navigate around your json @user3284259

Comment: fantastic, thanks very much for your help. it a lot clearer to me now :)

Answer (score 3):

You can get the value you seek with a one-liner.

For demo I'm using a Here-String for your json data, but probably you would read that from file with `$data = Get-Content -Path 'thefile.json' -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json`

```
$data = @'
{
    "profileVersion": 1,
    "profile": {
        "id": 0,
        "class": "PrimalPlayerDataBP_C",
        "names": ["PrimalPlayerDataBP_C_29", "ArkGameMode", "PersistentLevel", "Aberration_P", "/Game/Maps/Aberration/Aberration_P"],
        "properties": [{
            "name": "SavedPlayerDataVersion",
            "type": "IntProperty",
            "value": 8
        }, {
            "name": "HexagonCount",
            "type": "IntProperty",
            "value": 106860
        }, {
            "name": "MyPersistentBuffDatas",
            "type": "ArrayProperty",
            "arrayType": "ObjectProperty",
            "value": [1, 2, 3, 4]
        }],
        "extra": null
    }
}
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Then, to get the value from property with name "SavedPlayerDataVersion" you simply do:

```
$value = ($data.profile.properties | Where-Object { $_.name -eq "SavedPlayerDataVersion" }).value
```

Variable `$value` will now contain `8`

Answer (score 0):

Simple example:

```
$json = '{ "one": 1, "two": 2 }'
$data = $json | ConvertFrom-Json | Select one
$myVal = $data.one
$myVal
```

The printed output will be 1

In your case:

```
$json = '{
 "profileVersion": 1,
 "profile": {
     "id": 0,
     "class": "PrimalPlayerDataBP_C",
     "names": ["PrimalPlayerDataBP_C_29", "ArkGameMode", "PersistentLevel", "Aberration_P", "/Game/Maps/Aberration/Aberration_P"],
     "properties": [{
         "name": "SavedPlayerDataVersion",
         "type": "IntProperty",
         "value": 8
     }, {
         "name": "HexagonCount",
         "type": "IntProperty",
         "value": 106860
     }, {
         "name": "MyPersistentBuffDatas",
         "type": "ArrayProperty",
         "arrayType": "ObjectProperty",
         "value": [1, 2, 3, 4]
     }],
     "extra": null
 }}'
$data = $json | ConvertFrom-Json | Select -expand profile | Select -expand properties | Select name, type, value
$myVal = $data[0].value
$myVal
```